# Docker - Cannot Ping Server IPv6 or External IPv6 adresses from Container

Tags: docker, server, routes, ipv6

I have created a Docker container on my server (Ubuntu Server 16.04).
I can ping the local and global IPv6 of the docker interface from the container.
I can ping the global IPv6 of the container interface from the server but I have to specify the interface (using ping6 -I docker0).
Unfortunately I cannot ping External nor Server IPv6 from the container.

For your information: Ping External IPv6 from the server and SSH IPv6 server adress from another device is working fine.

I followed the official tutorial from docker website: https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/ipv6/

What am I missing ?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you used `--net=host` option at the time of creating container?

Comment: @Beginner Hi, I would like set up multiple containers on my server. the option you mention seems to set the server IPv6 adress for the container I have, but I cannot configure multiple different IPv6  that I could access externally.
Thank you by the way for the option I didn't know this one.